# Como deleto um row dinamicamente com Flask?

Tags: python, sql, mysqli, sqlite, flask

Pessoal tenho esse código no HTML

```
 {% for row in rows %}


    <div class="card border-success mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">

        <div class="card-header">{{ row['title'] }}</div>

        <div class="card-body">

            <p class="card-text">{{ row['text'] }}</p>
            <p id="whatsapp"> <img src="./static/whats.png" alt="whatsapp" height="15px" > {{ row['whatsapp'] }}</p>
            <form class="hidden" action="/delete" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value= "{{row['id']}}">
            </form>
                <a href="/delete" name="delete"> Delete Case</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor  %}
```

No flask, tenho esse:

```
@app.route("/delete")
def delete():


if request.method == "POST":
    id = request.form.get("id")
    db.execute("delete from cases where id = :id", id = id)


return redirect ('/ngoshome')
```

Por que não estou conseguindo deletar a row com o ID específico ?

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes? Qual o erro que está retornando?

Comment: No console não está aparecendo erro nenhum. ele simplesmente não deleta a row. E não consigo entender o porque não, no html pega o id pelo ROW[ID] e quando puxo no flask parece que não vincula, achei que desse jeito funcionaria

Comment: o que você está usando para manipular o banco de dados, sql alchemy? https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#deleting-records

Answer (score -3):

Tenta trocar o seu execute

db.execute("delete from cases where id =i d%s", (id_data,))
return redirect ('/ngoshome')